# How can I get the newly generated key from a .push using Fireproof for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise

I am using [fireproof](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fireproof) so that I can make my Firebase calls Promise-based. Seems like a pretty great idea, but I'm having a hard time getting the newly generated `key` from a `push`

```
firebase = new Firebase("https://mysite.firebaseio.com");

fbase = new Fireproof(firebase);

fbase.child("icm").push(newICM).then(function() {
  return console.log(KEY???);
});
```

How do I get the `key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, Fireproof doesn't pass the snapshot into `then()`. But it does return the original ref that `push()` return, so you can do:

```
var newRef = fbase.child("icm").push(newICM);
newRef.then(function() {
  console.log(newRef.key());
});
```

Note that you can't return a value now that hasn't been returned yet, so `return newRef.key()` will not work. If you myst return something, return the promise: `return newRef;` and then in the called do `newRef.then(...`.

Comment: `snapshot` returns `undefined`

Comment: Yeah. I see that too. Not sure how they pass thing in... checking... and updated

Comment: Seems like a hack, but I guess it'll do for now

Comment: Agreed, but it's the only way I could see to make it work. You can always fork Fireproof and pass the snapshot and/or ref into the fulfillment callback.